# Convert expansion panel functional component to Class Component

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, material-ui, react-state

I am relatively new to react. I have been trying to create a class component for below accordion expansion panel which is in functional format. I have trouble changing the handleChange event according to class component. I have tried all possible ways but i am failing.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
 import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
 import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
 import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
 import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

 }));

 export default function ControlledExpansionPanels() {


 const classes = useStyles();

 const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);


 const handleChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
 setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
 };


  return (

  <div className={classes.root}>

  <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>

   <ExpansionPanelSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
      id="panel1bh-header"
    >


    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>

    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>
  <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel2'} onChange={handleChange('panel2')}>
    <ExpansionPanelSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
      id="panel2bh-header"
    >

    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>

    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>


</div>

);

}
```

Please help!

Comment: useStyles is your custom hook?

Comment: @AtinSingh I believe this is a hook from material ui => https://material-ui.com/styles/api/

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: @DamianBusz just checked it out. The hook is declared just outside the main component so keeping the other code as it is we can just shift that classes const inside render. But I still don't understand why are you converting this functional component to class

Comment: @AtinSingh Thats a great question, I would personaly leave it as functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what issue you have if you dont describe it properly or deliver entire code, I did write your functional component into class component but I can't really check if it works or if there is any problem with handleChange. Please check and let me know what is the issue and if it corrected your problem.

```
export default class ControlledExpansionPanels extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {expanded: false}
    }

    handleChange =  panel => (event, isExpanded) =>{
    if(isExpanded) {
        this.setState({expanded: panel})
    } else {
        this.setState({expanded: false})
    }

    }
    render() {
        const classes = useStyles();
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
            <ExpansionPanel
              expanded={this.state.expanded === "panel1"}
              onChange={() => this.handleChange("panel1")}
            >
              <ExpansionPanelSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
              ></ExpansionPanelSummary>
              <ExpansionPanelDetails></ExpansionPanelDetails>
            </ExpansionPanel>
            <ExpansionPanel
              expanded={this.state.expanded === "panel2"}
              onChange={() => this.handleChange("panel2")}
            >
              <ExpansionPanelSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
                id="panel2bh-header"
              ></ExpansionPanelSummary>
              <ExpansionPanelDetails></ExpansionPanelDetails>
            </ExpansionPanel>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats correct, my bad. I forgot to add this.state infront as it is part of class component state. Too used to hooks I guess :) Edited the code in the post, should be good now

Comment: This worked after changing  expanded={expanded==='panel1'} to expanded={this.state.expanded==='panel1'}. Thank you!

Comment: @trek Your welcome. If this is a correct answer please mark this as correct answer for the people that come with similar problem and might find this topic of yours. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this

```
 export default class ControlledExpansionPanels extends React.Component {


 // const classes = useStyles();// // you can't use custom hook in class Component //

 const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false); // previous hook now not needed //

 state = { expanded: false }




handleChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
 // setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false); // //previous state manager , now not needed //
 isExpanded ? this.setState({ expanded: panel}) : this.setState({ expanded: false }) //new state manager//
 };

render() {
  return (

  <div className={classes.root}>

  <ExpansionPanel expanded={this.state.expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel1')}>

   <ExpansionPanelSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
      id="panel1bh-header"
    >


    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>

    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>
  <ExpansionPanel expanded={this.state.expanded === 'panel2'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel2')}>
    <ExpansionPanelSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
      id="panel2bh-header"
    >

    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>

    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
  </ExpansionPanel>


</div> 
)}
```

I think this should work.. other than your own hook everything's good.

Comment: If useStyle is not your custom hook then you can declare that const inside render before return as in @Damian's answer

Comment: throws error :  'expanded' is not defined  no-undef     in line <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel1')}>

Comment: oh yes my bad the expanded prop should be 
`expanded={this.state.expanded === "panel1"}`

same for panel2 one

Comment: edited it. Meanwhile if you want to refactor it you can destructure your state before return inside render function by `const { expanded } = this.state`

Comment: @trek no problem. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ControlledExpansionPanels extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {expanded: false}
}

handleChange =  panel => (event, expanded) =>{
if(expanded) {
    this.setState({expanded: panel})
} else {
    this.setState({expanded: false})
}

}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <ExpansionPanel
          expanded={this.state.expanded === "panel1"}
          onChange={this.handleChange("panel1")}
        >
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          ></ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails></ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanel
          expanded={this.state.expanded === "panel2"}
          onChange={this.handleChange("panel2")}
        >
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
            id="panel2bh-header"
          ></ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails></ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      </div>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Sanchari, thanks for your answer! Maybe you can edit your answer to be a bit more explanatory what your code sample does different to the one from the question and how it solves the issue?

This could help to spot the major changes more easily than scanning the whole code.